# How to get the time since when my Azure VM is stopped through Rest api or Java sdk

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-apps, azure-java-sdk

I am working on a Java application and my requirement is

**1. To check if my Azure Virtual Machine is in stopped state.**

**2. Since when (Date/Time) it is in stopped state.**

Azure Java SDK is preference but Rest API will also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information of VM on Azure through Java sdk `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachine`, for more details, you can reference the code [Get information about the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/java#get-information-about-the-vm).

**Update**

Java SDK `com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials` for vm authentication and method `statuses()` of SDK  `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachineInstanceView` to get vm state. If you want to get the time of stop state, you can read the time from the log.

Comment: I am sorry but It does not answer my question. I have already looked into this, if you have a clear answer please suggest.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful. I am looking on rest api reference to get the logs for a VM. In case you get anything relevant, please let me know.

Comment: @VineetKumar If the answer is helpful, you can accept it.